# AngularJS - DOM element attribute value update from controller or directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to modify the attribute of a multi select drop down after i uncheck all the checked items.

The drop down is as follows:

```
                    <multiselect class="input-xlarge" multiple="true"
                        id="env"
                        name="env"
                        ng-options="env.id as env.name for environment in environments"
                        ng-change="parseEnv(selectedEnv)"
                        ng-model="selectedEnv"
                        header="Environments"
                        options="e.name for e in environments"
                        change="selected()" >
                    </multiselect>
```

When ever the user selects one or more options, the header attribute in the multiselect is renamed with the number of items selected. Example "3 Selected". This event is triggered from a directive. If the user doesn't uncheck the options and clicks on any other element, i am able to uncheck the checked options but the header attribute name still shows as "3 selected".

AngularJS controller code:

```
        if(typeof item === 'object' && item !== null) {
            objectLength = Object.keys(item).length;
            if(objectLength > 0) {
                angular.forEach($scope.projects, function(reference) {
                  if(item.id != reference.id) {
                     angular.forEach($scope.selectedEnv, function(check) {
                       check.checked = false;
                     });
                  }
                });
}
}
```

How can i reset the header attribute back to the actual name from controller. If this is not possible from controller, how can i trigger the event from a directive which should be called after i uncheck all the checked options.

Comment: Please provide a runnable demo that demonstrates the issue as per [mre]

Comment: Please check the code in plunker: [https://plnkr.co/edit/jQmL8LU2wxjEIHbC?preview] Few things to mention in the plunker example: The first drop down is a single select drop down with name "Fruits". When i select a Fruit from the single select and in the second multi select drop down if i select more than one car, and again if i come back to fruits and select a different fruit, all the cars are deselected but the drop down name still shows "<number> selected". The event is managed from multiselect.js directive. How to set the select name to Cars if all the options are unchecked.